# Any way to remove picture in picture in firefox using javascript or css?

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-video, shadow-dom, firefox-developer-tools

I want to disable Picture in Picture feature for `<Video>` tag for my website due to some certification requirements but firefox does not allow to turn off. Any help would be appreciated.

- Firefox uses a `shadow-root`  with `{mode:"closed"}` to forcefully display Picture in Picture toogle [(See the image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk66l.png).
- Firefox also not supporting Picture-in-Picture API - [check this link](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/picture-in-picture/)

Note: I have also added `disablePictureInPicture` attribute but still it's not working for firefox.

```html
 <video width="400" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" controls  disablePictureInPicture></video>
```

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, there is currently (as of Firefox 72) no option for website authors to disable the button. Only users can [hide it via the Firefox settings](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/turn-picture-picture-mode).

Though a [request to add an API](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1610522) was created just a few hours ago.

Answer (score 3):

Videos without audio do not have the picture in picture button in firefox. This will not work for all use cases, but it might be useful in some situations. If you really depend on it and having audio you could try using a separate audio tag, but that could result in desynchronization issues.

You can do this e.g. using ffmpeg like described in [this](https://superuser.com/a/268986) question.

Comment: Great solution when using videos as background

Comment: I have a background MP4 with no audio and the PIP ui still displays (FF 96.0b9). Has this behavior changed or could there be something wrong with the way the video is formatted?

Comment: This still works on my website. Make sure there is no audio stream in the video. An audio stream with no volume/no sound will not work. You can use the `ffmpeg -i inputfile -c copy -an outputfile` command from the linked question to achieve this.
Note that the button is also hidden, when directly opening the video url in firefox without any html. So this does not depend on the HTML tag.

Comment: This is not true, at least in 2024. Firefox still displays the PiP button even for video without audio streams. The answer is that your video has to be less than 45 seconds to exempt from PiP, this is controlled by `media.videocontrols.picture-in-picture.video-toggle.min-video-secs` config value which is set to 45 by default.

Answer (score 1):

I have found one solution for this Bug 1610522 - Ability for developers to hide/disable picture-in-picture button.

**If you put video in Iframe `<iframe>` picture in picture feature. is not showing.**

```html
<div class="video-foreground">
          <iframe frameborder="0" width="350" height="250" allowfullscreen srcdoc="<html><head><style>body{margin: 0;padding: 0;}.bg-video-wrap {position: relative;overflow: hidden;width: 100%;height: 100vh;display: flex;}video {object-fit: cover;min-width: 100%;min-height: 100vh;z-index: 1;}</style></head><body><div class='bg-video-wrap'><video loop muted autoplay><source src='http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4' type='video/mp4'></video></div></body></html>" >
             
          </iframe>
        </div>
```

[here is the example](https://codepen.io/bibinrebo/pen/QWqvmBJ?editors=1010)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is clear, not confirmed if working

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.head.innerHTML += ` <style>
.pip-expanded, .pip-small, .pip-icon, .pip-explainer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    display :block;
}</style>`
```

Comment: I realize this is kind of old, but this isn't working for me.  Any explanation as to what you are attempting here?  Perhaps I need to modify it in a way I'm not immediately seeing.

Comment: try to add <style>        </style>